# Running Deep Learning code (written in MATLAB ) in Python/Octave

Tags: python, matlab, octave

I am working on a modified implementation of a project and it has a few MATLAB files:
https://github.com/marycore/SemanticRobot/blob/master/Matlab-code/

My lab doesn't use MATLAB so I tried running this in Octave, but it keeps throwing errors because the files use functions from Matlab's Deep Learning Toolbox. For example, for this https://github.com/ShreyaPandita01/SemanticRobot/blob/master/Matlab-code/createUnet.m file I get error due to https://in.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/nnet.cnn.layer.imageinputlayer.html

```
Octave evaluation error:
error: 'imageInputLayer' undefined near line 18 column 10
```

Ultimately I have to make a Python-based project(as I have never worked on MATLAB/Octave) and was planning on using the Oct2py library if the code ran in Octave.

Are there any other options for making this work other than re-coding the files by going through them line to line?

Comment: Unfortunately the answer is no. It is highly unlikely that you can get this to work on octave.Your best bet would be to find a U-Net implementation in python and try to replicate the steps implied by the matlab API.